# Why does this css postioning not work in FF8?

Tags: css, firefox

This code produces a calendar-like table with alternating vertical backgrounds, in Chrome, Safari and IE, but it just produces a tiny,messy little blob in the top left corner under Firefox 8.0.1 (have not tried other versions of FF).

I have tried making the "inner" `div`s as `span`s instead, but it makes no difference. The CSS validator says it's all fine. It just doesn't work in FF, and I don't know why it doesn't.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<title> Test CSS page </title>
<style type="text/css">
#Row1 {
 position:absolute;
 vertical-align:top;
  top: 2 px;
}
#Row2 {
 position:absolute;
 vertical-align:top;
  top: 102 px;
}
#Row3 {
 position:absolute;
 vertical-align:top;
  top: 202 px;
}
#Row4 {
 position:absolute;
 vertical-align:top;
  top: 302 px;
}
#Row5 {
 position:absolute;
 vertical-align:top;
  top: 402 px;
}
#col1 {
    text-align:right;
    position:absolute;
    height:100 px;
    width:79 px;
       left:4 px;
}
#col2 {
    text-align:right;
    position:absolute;
    height:100 px;
    width:79 px;
       left:83 px;
    background-color:#bfffbf;
}
#col3 {
    text-align:right;
    position:absolute;
    height:100 px;
    width:79 px;
       left:162 px;
}
#col4 {
    text-align:right;
    position:absolute;
    height:100 px;
    width:79 px;
       left:241 px;
    background-color:#bfffbf;
}
#col5 {
    text-align:right;
    position:absolute;
    height:100 px;
    width:79 px;
       left:320 px;
}
#col6 {
    text-align:right;
    position:absolute;
    height:100 px;
    width:79 px;
       left:399 px;
    background-color:#bfffbf;
}
#col7 {
    text-align:right;
    position:absolute;
    height:100 px;
    width:79 px;
       left:478 px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="Row1">
     <Div id="col1">1 </Div>
     <Div id="col2">2 </Div>

     <Div id="col3">3 </Div>
     <Div id="col4">4 </Div>
     <Div id="col5">5 </Div>
     <Div id="col6">6 </Div>
     <Div id="col7">7 </Div>
</div>
<div id="Row2">

     <Div id="col1">8 </Div>
     <Div id="col2">9 </Div>
     <Div id="col3">10 </Div>
     <Div id="col4">11 </Div>
     <Div id="col5">12 </Div>
     <Div id="col6">13 </Div>

     <Div id="col7">14 </Div>
</div>
<div id="Row3">
     <Div id="col1">15 </Div>
     <Div id="col2">16 </Div>
     <Div id="col3">17 </Div>
     <Div id="col4">18 </Div>

     <Div id="col5">19 </Div>
     <Div id="col6">20 </Div>
     <Div id="col7">21 </Div>
</div>
<div id="Row4">
     <Div id="col1">22 </Div>
     <Div id="col2">23 </Div>

     <Div id="col3">24 </Div>
     <Div id="col4">25 </Div>
     <Div id="col5">26 </Div>
     <Div id="col6">27 </Div>
     <Div id="col7">28 </Div>
</div>
<div id="Row5">

     <Div id="col1">29 </Div>
     <Div id="col2">30 </Div>
     <Div id="col3">31 </Div>
     <Div id="col4">32 </Div>
     <Div id="col5">33 </Div>
     <Div id="col6">34 </Div>

     <Div id="col7">35 </Div>
</div>
<br></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why on Earth!? Why are you not using a table?

Comment: I agree with @animuson, why aren't you using a table for data that is actually a table?

Comment: What validator said this was "all fine"?! Don't duplicate IDs, use a `<table>` instead, and there should be no space in `79 px` and the rest.

Comment: Quick suggestions: duplicate `id`s (an `id` ***must*** be unique within the document), `<Div>` instead of `<div>`. These may not be the actual problems, but they should be corrected.

Answer (score 2):

No space should be in between the number and the "px" unit.  Replace all those px positions.  For example, "2 px" with "2px".

EDIT: Also, you should consider modifying IDs "col1" - "col7" and make them classes instead.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you should avoid using duplicated IDs. Instead of `id="col1"` and `#col1`, use `class="col1"` and `.col1`.

Also remember to get rid of the space between number and unit in your CSS.

Comment: why bother duplicating someone else's answer? next time just up vote